# Compute shooting targets for the gunmen

Tags: algorithms, recreational-mathematics, game-theory

This is an extension of the well known "3 gunmen puzzle":

> N gunmen with hitting probabilities in (0,1] take turns to shoot at each other. Firing order is fixed (gunman 1 shoots first, then gunman 2 shoots, etc, as long as they are still alive). They repeat this process until only one survives. A gunman's goal is to maximize his surviving probability. Hitting probabilities are common knowledge.

To be specific, consider 10 gunmen with hitting probabilities 0.1, 0.2, ..., 0.9, 1. Who are they going to shoot when all are still alive? How should we formulate the problem so it can be solved by programming?

Comment: I can't help but think that this would also make an excellent challenge on Programming Puzzles and Code Golf SE.

Comment: @cobaltduck, I did post this on Programming Puzzles and Code Golf SE, but unfortunately it seems they think it off-topic.

Comment: Yes, I noticed, and I apologize.  While most SEs are looking for a single, canonical, correct answer, PGP prefers games where multiple players can enter, trying to score highest/lowest points and get the winning score.  PGP has a king-of-the-hill tag, for example.  Another commentor thought there might already be a challenge like yours under that tag.  I searched but couldn't find it.  Not too late to edit yours.